# Example of jQuery Mobile site with conditional/branching questions

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a JQM survey with branching questions--i.e. in a survey with questions 1-3, if you choose a particular answer on question 1, a question is dynamically added between questions 1 and 2.

UPDATE: I made an attempt ( https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17841063/site2/index-c1.html#page2 ) that works by matching the value of a radio button to the name of a hidden div--if there's a match, it unhides the div. The problem right now is that if you change your answer back to an option that wouldn't trigger the conditional question, it doesn't re-hide. For example, clicking No or Unsure in question A1 causes question A2 to appear, but if you then click Yes in A1, A2 still remains...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Place in this array the ID of the element you want to hide
var hide=['A2','A4'];
function setOpt()
{
resetOpt(); // Call the resetOpt function. Hide some elements in the "hide" array.
for(var i=0,sel=document.getElementsByTagName('input');i<sel.length;i++)
    {
    sel[i].onchange=function()
        {

        if(this.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase()!='div')
            resetOpt(); // Hides the elements in "hide" array when the first select element is choosen
        try
            {
            document.getElementById(this.value).style.display='';
            }
        catch(e){} ; // When the value of the element is not an element ID
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener('load',setOpt,false):
window.attachEvent('onload',setOpt);

function resetOpt()
{
for(var i=0;i<hide.length;i++) 
    document.getElementById(hide[i]).style.display='none'; // Hide the elements in "hide" array
}
</script>
```

Here's are the radio buttons that use the script above:

```
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <legend>(Question A1) A prominent accident smokes on top of the blessed reactionary?</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="aaa" id="aaa_0" value="notA2" />
          <label for="aaa_0">Yes</label>
          <input type="radio" name="aaa" id="aaa_1" value="A2" />
          <label for="aaa_1">No</label>
          <input type="radio" name="aaa" id="aaa_2" value="A2" />
          <label for="aaa_2">Unsure</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
     <div id="A2" data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <legend>(Question A2) Does a married composite remainder the shallow whistle??</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="bbb" id="bbb_0" value="" />
          <label for="bbb_0">Yes</label>
          <input type="radio" name="bbb" id="bbb_1" value="" />
          <label for="bbb_1">No</label>
          <input type="radio" name="bbb" id="bbb_2" value="" />
          <label for="bbb_2">Unsure</label>
       </fieldset>
      </div>
```

If anyone has ideas about fixing this, or examples of other ways to do branching forms, I'd be very grateful!

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: so when I click "No" or "Unsure" in Q1 of your example, Q2 appears. This is what you want, correct? But when I change my mind and now click "Yes" in Q1, Q2 should disappear again. Is that the problem you like to solve? You also might want to update your question and add the new code you mentioned in your UPDATE...

Comment: Hi Taifun--yes that is the problem I am trying to solve. Question and code updated... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just wondering but why are you using plain JavaScript to select the elements, add listeners etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I played around a little bit with your example, removed all your plain JavaScript and added some jQuery Mobile style script, [see working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/EgsZs/)

```
   <script>
      $("input[type='radio']").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
        var mySelection = $('input[name=aaa]:checked').val();
        //alert(mySelection);
        if (mySelection == "A2") {
          $('#A2').removeClass('ui-hidden-accessible');
        } else {
          $('#A2').addClass('ui-hidden-accessible');
        };
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Taifun. This works but one of the nice things about the original code is that it could work automatically based on the div ID matching the value of the radio option. Can you think of any way to have that functionality using jQuerymobile-style script?

Comment: probably yes, but currently I don't think that I'm motivated enough to play around more...